# Can I disable the ability for simultaneous checkout in Perforce

Tags: perforce

I am using perforce with Siemens TIA software. I would like to disable the ability for a file to be checked out by more than one person at a time since the files being used are binary and therefore the merge tools don't work all too well for multiple updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In perforce lingo you want to the make the file exclusive, or +l.  If you are using the visual application p4v, you can check out the file, right click and then go "Change Filetype...".  You can do the same thing on the command line:

```
p4 edit -t binary+l //somepath/somefile
```

which can include wild cards if you want to modify a bunch of files.  The deeper solution is to use the `p4 typemap` command so you can tell perforce to understand your extension as always being binary and exclusive.

There are some workflow challenges with making a file exclusive.  Imagine user A checks out the file exclusive but then goes home and is sick the next day?  User B can't check out the file to do the work while user A is a away and you need an administrator to either unlock user A's computer or to revert the check out.  User B can edit the file in "non-exclusive mode" by using the command line:

```
p4 edit -t binary //somepath/somefile_someone_else_has_exclusive
```

And then check it in, but now user A is going to have a mess on their hands when they do get back in and they want to check in.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted all files in the depot to have the same chekin/out preferences so using p4 typemap +l //depot_name/... worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

See the "Locking files" section of the [p4 resolve documentation](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/05_resolve.html) - and note what you'll be losing if you do this.